# Cannot insert values in custom message

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi and thanks for reading.
I am trying to add a custom message to my project, but for some reason I cannot update the values.
I simplified the message package to hold a simple String type which still doesn't work.
the message catkin_pkg builds without any errors.
features_msg.msg:

`std_msgs/String tmp`

in the .cpp file, I am calling:

```
    features_tracking_msg::features_msg features;
    features.tmp = "testing";
```

and getting: **No viable overloaded '='**

Any help would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398304/cannot-insert-values-in-custom-message/) by [AibohphobiA](https://answers.ros.org/users/57608/aibohphobia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2022-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`std_msgs/String` is not a `std::string`.

It's a class which has a `std::string` as one of its members. That member is called `data`.

So you'd need to assign `"testing"` to `features.tmp.data`, not to `features.tmp` directly (as that would require a suitable overload of `=` / conversion operator to be available, which would convert `std::string` to `std_msgs::String`).

However, having written that: if you're already creating a custom message, I would recommend to directly use the `string` primitive type for `tmp`, instead of `std_msgs/String`.

The former is the type to use for message fields. The latter is a type to use when directly publishing a string to a topic.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AibohphobiA](https://answers.ros.org/users/57608/aibohphobia/) on 2022-04-05**:
Thanks!
I don't know how, but in the following tutorial(which I used) he uses std_msgs::String and then assigns an std::string to it (which works somehow):
[link text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yO4G1dR1mls&ab_channel=ROBOMECHTRIX)

Thanks for your help!